# Assign result of DateTime.TryParse or null

Tags: c#

I'm not sure why I cannot perform such a action

my logic behind this:

if parsing of string to datetime failed then assign null, otherwise outed value

```
using System;

public class Program
{   
    public class Test
    {
        public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var test = new Test
        {
            Date = DateTime.TryParse("string", out var dt) ? dt : null
        };
    }
}
```

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between `null` and `DateTime`

But my type is `DateTime?`, so what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to add casting into `DateTime?`

```
Date = (DateTime.TryParse("string", out var dt) ? dt : (DateTime?)null)
```